# Combined templete not showing full results laravel

Tags: laravel, include

I am having some trouble combining 2 templates together where I want the popup button to be shown together with user information. When I try doing it, it only show a few information inside instead of all. Why is that?

Background information: I am trying to make a page where it shows user information and also a button where when the user click it, they can submit some details inside. But for some reason when I combine them together it is either the form only show a bit of info with no button or show even lesser info but with button.

Here is the code for the popup button:

evaltest.blade.php (I want the information from test.blade.php to be shown here but right now only a few information is being shown)

```
    <html>
    <head> 
        <title>Popup form </title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">    
        <link href="{{ asset('css/elements.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-43981329-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
    </head> 
     <!-- body starts here -->
     <body id ="bdy" style="overflow:hidden;">

     <div id="abc">

         <!-- Popup div starts here -->
     <div id="popupContact"> 

        <!-- contact us form -->
             <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/evaltest/'.$data0->id) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <img id ="close" src="{{ URL::to('/image') }}/3.png" onclick ="div_hide()">
             <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$data0->id}}">

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2"><b>Recommendation:</b></label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" id ="recommendation" name="recommendation" value="No"> No<br>
          </div>
      </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
                  <input id= "submit" type="submit" href="javascript: check_empty()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
     </div> 
    <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
    </div>
    <!-- Display Popup Button -->
//this will show a few info but no button       
@include('test')
    <h1>Click Button to Evaluate</h1>
    <button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>
        <script src="{{ asset('/js/my_js.js') }}"></script>
//this will show even lesser info but button is shown
//@include('test')
    </body>
    </html>
```

test.blade.php (there are more information inside but I only put some as an example of how I got the information)

```
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
    <b>Alias: </b>{{ $object->Alias }}<br><br>
    <b>Email: </b>{{$object->Email}}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The test.blade.php itself is showing all the information, but when combine it doesn't show everything

Comment: `div_show()` ????

Comment: That is the button to show the form when it has been clicked (I got it from this website while trying to do a popup form, https://www.formget.com/how-to-create-pop-up-contact-form-using-javascript/)

Comment: All the things are working but when I combine 2 blade using include it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `$data` variable where you call `@include`. For example `@include('test',[$data])`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: you mean @include('inc.Name,Email',[$data])?

Comment: Then what if I have multiple variable? Example $data1, $data2 as well, how do I do it? Or I just have to do it multiple times?

Comment: pass them like an array. Ex: [$data1, $data2..]

Comment: I tried just using $data1 first, it still only show some of the information, I did a right click, view page source and it shows all the codes with the value being shown but not showing in the view

Comment: Ops sorry I meant just $data, it only shows Name, Email inside the view but not Alias but when I right click view page source, the code shows that the Alias value and other kind of information are there

Comment: if your $data1 is an array you should pass it like @include('test',$data)

Comment: @VajiiraPradbuddhaka yes I did do that but my view still doesn't change, it just show a few information only, but I know that the data are already loaded

Comment: yes then see your for loop, it accepts a $data as an array(probably json) so just try to hardcode it like @include('test',[['email'=>"abc@xyz.com", 'Name'=>"vajira", 'Alias'=>"..."], [<also define array here like that>]])  After make sure that your $data is like that

Comment: The email, name, alias and those other information already contain data inside, all I want now is to show their data but the view is only showing certain data and not all. Maybe I post a screenshot inside a question so it will be much more easier to understand